# Is a paper airplane made of a $100 bill muktzah

Tags: shabbat, money, muktzeh

Is a paper airplane made of a $100 bill muktzah? So as to simplify the situation and avoid other Shabbos issues regarding paper, oragami, etc, assume the paper airplane was folded before the onset of Shabbat/chag.

Comment: Mukse machmat chisaron kis would certainly apply here, happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: The MB 308 in the Hakdama says that money is muktzeh machmas gufo. In 308:7 he says that if you set aside a muktzeh machmas gufo with the intent to use it then it’s permitted. Logic would follow that making it into an airplane would be considered setting it aside for it to be used

Comment: @RabbiKaii it’s not chisoron kis since the dollar bill doesn’t lose value if it’s crunched up, and he obviously isn’t scared of it getting lost

Comment: @Chatzkel thanks for making me happy. Wondering what makes you believe he obviously isn't scare of it getting lost, and could you bring a source for me to read about how to decide if something is considered high value and what it depends on?

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/4956/

Comment: @Chatzkel the bullet points under the shiur do not deal with this, or at least do not back up or disagree with your point/

Comment: It’s a general outline of what is and what it depends on to become chisaron kis